# How to install an ASP.NET web forms project locally?

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, dependency-management, windows-package-manager

Recently, I've tried installing an ASP.NET 4.0 Web Forms Web Application locally...I've copied the Web.config file into the project and launched the following command

```
Update-Package -Reinstall
```

So I was expecting that the NuGet Package Manager would install all the packages listed on the packages.config file since he will find out that they're all missing.

But unfortunately, the package manager didn't install all the packages listed on the packages.config file...So I had thousands of build error messages due to missing dependencies.

After a day and half of managing problems with the dependencies versions I'm managed to make it work. But as you know it wasn't an easy task for me since I'm new to this environnement.

I assumed that the NuGet package manager had some issues installing these dependencies.

- How should I proceed to install locally any ASP.NET web application I'm working on ?
- How do I know if a build error is caused by dependecies or their versions ?
- How do I prevent this from happening again ?

Comment: Show the log generated by that command, so that others can see what might be wrong. Remember the fact that your screen cannot be seen over the internet.

Answer (score 0):

Right click to the solution in VS and open the nuget package and go to browse. Type ASP.NET and choose whatever you need and then put a check onto the solution and click install and you should be able to use it normaly. Hope i've helped